# No displayName after editing or creating

Tags: issues

Since the last CiviCRm version 4.7.21 to 4.7.23, I have the display_name empty. There is also the trouble for the sort_name.

I found the report of  SarahG (FountainTribe) here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33928.msg143820#msg143820 
It states that :

> The return value from "CRM_Utils_Address::format" is returning an
>   empty string for the display name and the sort name. Those empty
>   strings cause the calling function to use email address instead.

I applied her solution :

---

In the file /CRM/Contact/BAO/Individual.php (around 210 -215) 
I replaced the line:
Code: 
$displayName = CRM_Utils_Address::format($formatted, $format,  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, $tokenFields );

New line: 
Code:
$displayName = $firstName." ".$lastName;

Did similar replacement for the $sortName variable.

---

This solved the trouble. But as she stated, it is only a temporary solution.

Does anyone still encountered this issue with CiviCRm version 4.7.23 ?

Comment: Hello, here's a follow-up after testing the Release Candidate CiviCRm version 4.7.24.
All the issues with displayName and probably from the function CRM_Utils_Address::format are solved. So it seems that issue is resolved from the 4.7.24 that is due to be out in September.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 4.7.24 then to 4.7.25, I observed that the issue with the No displayName after editing or creating came back.
This is strange that Release Candidate CiviCRm version 4.7.24 was the only fix.
Does-it concern other people and other installation ?

Comment: Upgrading will overwrite your modification to the core file.  You'll need to figure out what's going on with your underlying data to resolve this fully.

Comment: Yes Jon, after any update the problem comes back. Now it is CiviCRM 5.2.1 and I still have to replace the line. I still have no clue where this comes from.